# Can I include the sessionStorage.getItem() value in the <a> tag href string?

Tags: javascript, html, href, session-storage

The URL to be moved is get from the database and replaced directly with the `<a>` tag href. 
I need to add the sessionStorage.getItem() value to it at the end of url. 
The only thing I can change now is the value in the database, so can I include sessionStorage.getItem() in the string itself?

Currently, the `<a>` tag href value is included like this.

```
<a href="{{item.template_url}}" target="_blank">
```

Is there a way to put the sessionStorage.getItem() value directly?

```
template_url = http://localhost:8080/template/user/{{sessionStorage.getItem('user_id')}}
```

Comment: Is this template engine running client side in browser? If not , localStorage doesn't exist server side

Comment: http://localhost:8080/template is running on the client side in browser .!

Comment: That doesn't explain where you do the interpolation of the `{{ }}` blocks. Those are not interpolated by html in browser and require a template engine like ejs, handlebars, pug etc to parse them